# JavaScript date conflict with month

Tags: javascript

Hi I am using following code to format my date string

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
                  "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
                  "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var AddedDate = new Date('04/11/2016 11:36:15');
alert(AddedDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[AddedDate.getMonth()] + '\'' + AddedDate.getYear());
```

here the input date format is in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss
But when I `getDate()` it gives date as 11 and `getmonth()` gives as Apr. How can i fix this. Please help.
And also is there a way to get year as 16 for 2016.

Current Output i am getting is `11 Apr'116`

Expected Output is `04 Nov'16`

Comment: what do you expect to get?

Comment: I want to get -> 04 Nov'16

Comment: you really, really want to use http://momentjs.com/ instead of trying to do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default date string format in Javascript is `mm/dd/yyyy`. So in your case it is considered `11 April 2016`. FOr month itself, javascript function `getMonth()` will return month number in 0 based index. so `April == 3`.
to getting the year `2016` you should use `getFullYear()` instead

if you want to force javascript to get input `dd/mm/yyyy` You have to do it yourself, like this:

```
var myDate = "04/11/2016".split("/");
var AddedDate = new Date(myDate[2], myDate[1] - 1, myDate[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the date in dd/mm/year format.I took off the time part and split string into array and created a date with date,month and year

To get short year,i have taken the substr(2,2)

check the snippet

```js
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var dateString = '04/11/2016 11:36:15';

dateString = dateString.split(' ')[0];

var dateParts = dateString.split("/");

var date = dateParts[2];
var month = dateParts[1] - 1;


var dateObject = new Date(date, month, dateParts[0]);


var yearShort = dateObject.getFullYear().toString()
alert(dateObject.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[dateObject.getMonth()] + '\'' + yearShort);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: with out getting full year can I get 16 only?

Comment: And also this date is a value I cannot change the format it comes. I just hard corded it here to ask the question only.

Comment: Modified the code..please check it if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

The just do `new Date('11/04/2016 11:36:15');`

The format is month/day/year etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong date format into `new Date()`. The valid date string format is stated [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp).

> **ISO Date**  : "2015-03-25" (The International Standard)
>   
>   **Short Date**: "03/25/2015"
>   
>   **Long Date** : "Mar 25 2015" or "25 Mar 2015"
>   
>   **Full Date** : "Wednesday March 25 2015"